# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() not working on linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

So I'm trying to create an application that requires the reading of scripts in a sub-folder called "scripts". My code I'm having issues with:

```
string script = Console.ReadLine();
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string sciptpath  = path + "/scripts/" + script;
```

This works fine on Windows. But on Linux (running using Mono Runtime) it goes to the current users home Directory...not the directory of the executable. Is this a bug?  And can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Have you checked Mono compatibility against http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility? You could also try the Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA) tool which helps  identify issues you may have when porting your .Net application to Mono (http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).

Comment: Not your problem/question, but don't concatenate paths, use Path.Combine instead: string scriptpath = Path.Combine (path, "scripts", script); - it will work correctly on both windows and linux.

Answer (score 12):

It's not that it needs "fixing" it's that the current directory is not what you think it is. The current directory is the directory that "has focus" for relative paths. Regardless where your EXE is, your current directory can be anywhere else, or may even change during execution.

What you want is:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: thanks this worked great. I actually only had to do Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)); to fix the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't modify the current directory unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: As a general rule, you should treat the current directory as a resource that's controlled by the user and you should use and/or it when processing requests that were initiated by the user (for instance opening a file from some dialog in a GUI application).

And you should only modify it when the user expects this.

When you automatically load additional files that are part of your application, that's usually invisible to the user or at least the user should not be bothered with it.  Therefor, compute the path based on your application's installation directory and don't use the current dir.

Comment: So you would do `var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath); var scriptdir = Path.Combine (path, "scripts"); var script = Path.Combine (scriptdir, script);`

Comment: @MartinBaulig, exactly. Just maybe with the var, they're just strings.