# What is the equivalent of Server.MapPath in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this line in some code I want to copy into my controller, but the compiler complains that

> The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

```
var UploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads")
```

How can I achieve the equivalent in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Use `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` and then use `Path.Combine` with second argument assigned to target directory. See [Server.MapPath Equivalent in ASP.NET Core](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core) for further reference.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**UPDATE: IHostingEnvironment is deprecated. See update below.**

In Asp.NET Core 2.2 and below, the hosting environment has been abstracted using the interface, [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

The [ContentRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.contentrootpath?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_ContentRootPath) property will give you access to the absolute path to the application content files.

You may also use the property, [WebRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_WebRootPath) if you would like to access the web-servable root path (www folder by default)

You may inject this dependency into your controller and access it as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

        return Content(webRootPath + "\n" + contentRootPath);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE - .NET CORE 3.0 and Above**

IHostingEnvironment has been marked obsolete with .NET Core 3.0 as pointed out by @[amir133](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9076865/amir133). You should be using [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1) instead of [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.0). Please refer to that answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934673/7960700).

Microsoft has neatly segregated the host environment properties among these interfaces. Please refer to the interface definition below:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
{
  public interface IHostEnvironment
  {
    string EnvironmentName { get; set; }
    string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    string ContentRootPath { get; set; }
    IFileProvider ContentRootFileProvider { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
{
  public interface IWebHostEnvironment : IHostEnvironment
  {
    string WebRootPath { get; set; }
    IFileProvider WebRootFileProvider { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited this so you're not copying @aamir133's answer.

Comment: Thanks..In fact, i didn't copy aamir's code, I copied my initial answer and replaced the interface. :) But what you said makes sense, I have edited again and just linked the answer to aamir's and also provided the interface definition for people who are interested to know how the properties are laid out among those interfaces..

Comment: It's not clear what the actual answer to the OP is?!

Comment: I hate dependency injection.  How can I get the hosting environment without using DI?

Comment: Just ran into this while trying to freshen up a site to have new content. Why was this done? It certainly seems less intuitive to me. In fact, gone seem to be the days when Microsoft made development fun. Now code all seems to look like some kind of hack job by new generation kids who don't want to write all of the code down.

Comment: what's the answer? how do i use the code above to mimic Server.Map? what a treadure hunt

Answer (score 150):

### .NET 6 (.NET Core 3 and above)

For example, I want to locate `~/wwwroot/CSS`

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public YourController (IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment= webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string contentRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

        string path ="";
        path = Path.Combine(webRootPath , "CSS");
        //or path = Path.Combine(contentRootPath , "wwwroot" ,"CSS" );
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

### Some Tricks

Also if you don't have a controller or service, follow the last Part and register its class as a singleton.
Then, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<your_class_Name>();
```

Finally, inject `your_class_Name` where you need it.

---

### .NET Core 2

For example, I want to locate `~/wwwroot/CSS`

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _HostEnvironment; //difference is here : IHostingEnvironment  vs I*Web*HostEnvironment 

    public YourController (IHostingEnvironment HostEnvironment)
    {
        _HostEnvironment= HostEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string webRootPath = _HostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string contentRootPath = _HostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

        string path ="";
        path = Path.Combine(webRootPath , "CSS");
        //or path = Path.Combine(contentRootPath , "wwwroot" ,"CSS" );
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

### MoreDetails

Thanks to @Ashin but `IHostingEnvironment` is obsoleted in MVC Core 3!!

According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749) :

Obsolete types (warning):

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.EnvironmentName
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EnvironmentName
```

New types:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment : IHostEnvironment
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Environments
```

So you must use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead of `IHostingEnvironment`.

Comment: Thanks amir133 for pointing it out..i have updated the answer

Comment: @ashin You updated the answer to write exactly what amir133 wrote. Why not just mention refer to amir133's answer instead?

Comment: I don't know how to inject this? Where is implementation class?

Comment: @vesa inject it in configure in startup

Answer (score 66):

The accepted answer's suggestion is good enough in most scenarios, however - since it depends on *Dependency Injection* - is limited to Controllers and Views: in order to have a proper `Server.MapPath` replacement that can be accessed from non-singleton helper classes we can add the following line(s) of code at the end of the `Configure()` method of the app's `Startup.cs` file:

```
// setup app's root folders
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("ContentRootPath", env.ContentRootPath);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("WebRootPath", env.WebRootPath);
```

This way we'll be able to retrieve them from within any class (including, yet not limiting to, Controllers and Views) in the following way:

```
var contentRootPath = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("ContentRootPath");
var webRootPath = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("WebRootPath");
```

This can be further exploited to create a static helper method that will allow us to have the same functionality as the good old `Server.MapPath`:

```
public static class MyServer 
{
    public static string MapPath(string path)
    {
        return Path.Combine(
            (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("ContentRootPath"), 
            path);
    }
}
```

Which can be used it in the following way:

```
var docPath = MyServer.MapPath("App_Data/docs");
```

For additional info regarding this approach and a bit of background, take a look at [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-server-mappath-equivalent-absolute-path/) on my blog.

Comment: NOTE: The original .NET Framework Server.MapPath worked slightly differently returning d:\website\file.txt when called from with a path = "\file.txt", this returns just "file.txt".  Just remove the initial "\", to get similar results.  Hope that helps

Comment: Where does the env variable come from?

Comment: @RolandWales, if you're using ASP.NET Core 6 with the new hosting model (without `Startup.cs` file), your `env` variable equivalent (originally a parameter of the `Configure` method in the `Startup.cs` class) is the `builder.Environment` property (in the `Program.cs` file).

Comment: @Darkseal it seems to me .NET Core 6 removed AppDomains? Would it affect your answer then? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable

Comment: @joedotnot : `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` is still working in .NET 6 and .NET 7, while other methods (such as `AppDomain.SetCachePath`) have been deprecated and are not supported anymore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.currentdomain?view=net-7.0

Comment: Can I use in ***minimal API Net 6*** ?

Comment: I like it but I suggest some enhancement: use `WebRootPath` instead of `ContentRootPath` for static files and above all, trim leading path separators with `Path.Combine`: `Path.Combine((string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("WebRootPath"), 
            path.TrimStart(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))`

Answer (score 9):

use for example: `var fullPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");`

Comment: this answer won't work for Linux environment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916204/directory-getcurrentdirectory-not-working-on-linux

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I've seen this mentioned yet:

```
var webPath = WebHostEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(path).PhysicalPath;
var contentPath = WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(path).PhysicalPath;
```

(As mentioned in another answer, `WebHostEnvironment` would be an instance of `IWebHostEnvironment` that gets injected via the constructor.)

The `path` in this case could be something like "/some/folder" or "/some/file".

Some pros and cons:

- The file/folder may have to exist for these methods to return the path (though my testing showed each method handled these differently).
- This ought to provide a bit more defensive coding around things like paths that are formed in a way to gain access to files outside of the website folder. Using `Path.Combine` would not offer this safety.