# How to save Images to different folders in database using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that is working fine to save images to different folders and sub folders. But when I want to do similarly in ASP.NET Core 2.2, it is not working as it is and I need help to solve this problem and I would appreciate your help very much.

Here is my ASP.NET MVC version that not working in ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```
public ActionResult AddCar(CarVM model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        Car  c = new Car();
        c.Name = model.Name;
        c.Mileage = model.MileAge;

        db.Car.Add(c);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Get Inserted Id;
        int id = c.CarId; 
    }

    // to insert Image of the car in different folders in ASP.NET MVC I do like this, but this not working in ASP.NET Core 2.2
    // Create necessary directories
    var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Images\\Uploads", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

    // I add folder "CarsImage" because I have other Products image too
    var pathString1 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage");
    var pathString2 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString());
    var pathString3 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString() + "\\Thumbs");
    var pathString4 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString() + "\\Gallery");
    var pathString5 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString() + "\\Gallery\\Thumbs");

    // Check if directory exist, if not then create them
    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString1))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString1);

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString2))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString2);

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString3))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString3);

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString4))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString4);

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString5))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString5);

    // Check if file was uploaded
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // Get file extension
        string ext = file.ContentType.ToLower();

        // Verify extension
        if (ext != "image/jpg" &&
            ext != "image/jpeg" &&
            ext != "image/pjpeg" &&
            ext != "image/gif" &&
            ext != "image/x-png" &&
            ext != "image/png")
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                model.Categories = new SelectList(db.Category.ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
                model.Mileages = new SelectList(db.MileAge.ToList(), "MileAgeId", "Mile");

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The image was not uploaded - Wrong image extension");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // Init image name
        string imageName = file.FileName;

        // Save image name to Car table
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Car dto = db.Car.Find(id);
            dto.ImageName = imageName;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Set Original and image paths
        var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString2, imageName);
        var path2 = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString3, imageName);

        // Save Original
        file.SaveAs(path); // Not working in core

        // Create and save thumb
        WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);  // WebImage not working in core
        img.Resize(200, 200);
        img.Save(path2);
    }
}
```

So I have tried with `IFormFile`.... and

```
string uploadFolder = Path.Combine(hostingEnvirnment.WebRootPath, "images\\upload");
```

But I don't how to do. Please help!

Comment: Any errors while uploading?

Comment: try the following path: "/images/upload"

Comment: @CyberProgs , thank you for your response but it's not the main  problem. I Think it's different way to write code MVC vc Core for example how to get originalDirectory or the path

Comment: @PrashantPimpale , thank you for your responseFor the most code there is not error message  I Think it's different way to write code MVC vc Core for example how to get originalDirectory or the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core , you could use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the current working directory of the application and combine the folder path under the static file root directory .

```
var originalDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Images\\Uploads");
```

Then use `Path.Combine()` to set the original and image paths , and you could save the files of type `IFormFile` like below :

```
// Set Original and image paths
   var filePath = Path.Combine(pathString2, imageName);
   var filePath2 = Path.Combine(pathString3, imageName);

// Save Original
   file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
```

For saving the thumbnail image , you could Installed `System.Drawing.Common` package and use the below code :

```
Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
Image newImage = GetReducedImage(200, 200, stream);

newImage.Save(filePath2);

public Image GetReducedImage(int width, int height, Stream resourceImage)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(resourceImage);
            Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

            return thumb;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
public readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public HomeController( ApplicationDbContext context)
{
     _context = context;
}
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCar(Car model, IFormFile file)
    {
        Car c = new Car();
        c.Name = model.Name;
        c.Mileage = model.MileAge;
        _context.Car.Add(c);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // Get Inserted Id;
        int id = c.CarId;

        // Create necessary directories 
        var originalDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Images\\Uploads");

        // different image folder
        var pathString1 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage");
        var pathString2 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString());
        var pathString3 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString() + "\\Thumbs");
        var pathString4 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "CarsImage\\" + id.ToString() + "\\Gallery");

        // Check if directory exist, if not then create them
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathString1))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString1);

        if (!Directory.Exists(pathString2))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString2);

        if (!Directory.Exists(pathString3))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString3);

        if (!Directory.Exists(pathString4))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString4);

        // Check if file was uploaded
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            // Get file extension
            string ext = file.ContentType.ToLower();

            // Verify extension
            if (ext != "image/jpg" &&
                ext != "image/jpeg" &&
                ext != "image/pjpeg" &&
                ext != "image/gif" &&
                ext != "image/x-png" &&
                ext != "image/png")
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    model.Categories = new SelectList(db.Category.ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
                    model.Mileages = new SelectList(db.MileAge.ToList(), "MileAgeId", "Mile");

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The image was not uploaded - Wrong image extension");
                    return View();
                }
            }

            // Init image name
            string imageName = file.FileName;

            // Save image name to Car table
             Car dto = _context.Car.Find(id);
             dto.ImageName = imageName; 
             _context.SaveChanges();

            // Set Original and image paths
            var filePath = Path.Combine(pathString2, imageName);
            var filePath2 = Path.Combine(pathString3, imageName);

            // Save Original
            file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));

            // Create and save thumb
            Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            Image newImage = GetReducedImage(200, 200, stream);
            newImage.Save(filePath2);
        }
        return View();
    }

    public Image GetReducedImage(int width, int height, Stream resourceImage)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(resourceImage);
            Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
            return thumb;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IHostingEnvironment` to get the application path in ASP.NET Core. Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core) for more details.