# How to get a FileSystem path to save a file in ASPNET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller where I upload a file

Here is the controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace TodoApi.Controllers {
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {

        public FileUploadController()
        {
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            var filePath = Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles/Foo");
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build it claims that there is no Server in context. I tried `HttpContext.Current.Server` `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` but I always get no X in context. What I'm missing?

Here is csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

Here is the current error

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 61.19 ms for /Users/gecko/code/TodoApi2/TodoApi2.csproj.
Controllers/FileUploadController.cs(24,28): error CS0103: The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context [/Users/gecko/code/TodoApi2/TodoApi2.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Controllers/FileUploadController.cs(24,28): error CS0103: The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context [/Users/gecko/code/TodoApi2/TodoApi2.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.50
```

I uploaded the code to this repo https://github.com/dhilst/TodoApi2

Comment: according to your error  The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
the reference to System.Web was not added to the project. Note you can add an using statement and not get an error without adding the reference.

Comment: I tried that too, I will edit the question

Comment: It may be something regarding version?

Comment: I simplified the code and upload it  to github

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/49398965/3773983 ?

Comment: No but it does a lot of sense to me, I will try out! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Dave, that answer helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Server.MapPath in your API, use HostingEnvironment instead:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/Foo");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I'm pretty new to aspnet, what is the difference? I got Server.MapPath from the documentation examples

Comment: I'm trying to find a link to the documentation, but what I recall is: Server.MapPath() uses internally HostingEnvironment.MapPath, however Server.MapPath requires the HttpContext before calling HostingEnvironment.MapPath() and HttpContext is available depending on how the service is hosted, in your case was not available.

Comment: I tried system.web.hosting environment wihtou success too, I'm using .net core