# How can I get a list of file paths for static image files in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, wwwroot

I'm trying to get a list of the static files inside of my wwwroot folder in a Blazor WebAssembly project. This is what I've tried so far:

```
string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\images", "*.jpg");
```

I get this error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find a part of the path '/wwwroot\images'.
```

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/wwwroot\images'.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of Server.MapPath in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This only applies to Blazor Server- I am using Blazor WebAssembly.

Comment: I don't think you can run this code in Blazor WebAssembly App. I know that if you want to read the content of a json file located in the wwwroot folder, you should use HTTP calls. But to retrieve the names of the files can be only done, I guess, using JSInterop. Try JSInterop, perhaps you'd succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought was that `Directory.GetFiles()` shouldn't be supported on Blazor WebAssembly - you are not allowed on the filesystem.
But running `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(".")` gives this output:

```
./tmp
./home
./dev
./proc
./zoneinfo
```

which are some pre-packaged files&folders you can get at. But none of them contain wwwroot and the contents you're after.

So you can use `Http.GetStreamAsync()` or `Http.GetByteArrayAsync()` to get the contents of an image file *you already know the name of*. There is no direct way to scan a folder: a security feature.  (I know you can configure ISS to allow 'browsing' a folder but that goes against best practices and gives you HTML to parse).

If you do want to scan a folder, build an API to do so. You need to run that  on the server.

Comment: So if you're running a Blazor wasm standalone (not hosted) app, there's no way to enumerate the `content-root` or `web-root` paths?

Comment: No, not that I know of. And that is right, there is no web-root path after launch. That is a server thing. Ask an API when you need something.

Comment: I am creating a static blog with blazor wasm and the only way that worked for me was to construct a `Json` metadata file with a prebuild script and requesting it with the `HttpClient` in order to keep track of file count, dates and other metadata. hopefully this will be easier in the future.

Comment: It is a little easier now, see https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess

Answer (score -1):

Please get "images" directory path like below:

```
string folderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images");
string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.jpg");
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Has this solution been tested? First of all, it stands in contradiction to the previous answer. Furthermore, also in 2022 it does not seem to work.