# Upgrade .net 4.8 to net 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I tried to migrate an web application  from .net 4.7 to net 5. How can i find equivalent `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`? But **MapPath**  doesn't exist in net 5?

best regards

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core) answer your question?

Comment: @Llama no. What i want to Maps a virtual path to physical path on server.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core

Comment: [HostingEnvironment Equivalent For MapPath](https://forums.asp.net/t/2005166.aspx?HostingEnvironment+Equivalent+For+MapPath) • [What is the difference between Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core)