# File path in Blazor serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor serverside application hosted on iis,I need the path for a specific folder elsewhere on the server?
What would also help is a an equivalent of server.MapPath.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of Server.MapPath in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: What does "elsewhere on the server" mean?  Is it below the wwwroot folder or not?

Comment: Will the IIS worker have permission to access the path?

Comment: Elsewher in the server is not in the wwwroot