# How to access WebRootPath anywhere in the project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I'd like to access IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath anywhere in the asp.net core mvc application. For instance, some random class deep in the class hierarchy. Is there a static class or some other method to do so?

I am aware that I can inject IWebHostEnvironment or that I can cache the value on the startup of the application.  My question is strictly about accessing it without these methods.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft devs permit accessing to the root path without first controller injection of `IWebHostEnvironment` or through `HttpContextAccessor` in static class

Comment: I think "~" will always get you there... so maybe Server.MapPath("~")  might give you the path.

Comment: I sometimes use AppContext.BaseDirectory for uploading files (I create directories there)... that should be where the .dll/exe is run. (which is outside of web path?)

Comment: `Server.MapPath("~")` has been deprecated and does not work in `Asp.Net Core`. [Check this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @pcalkins WebRootPath is the wwwroot folder.  So AppContext won't work here.

Comment: Is it possible that we hardcode the path in the configuration? I mean before we deploy the app, we modify the configuration...

Comment: No there's no static

Comment: in my case AppContext.BaseDirectory + "\wwwroot" gives you the path to my js, css, and lib folders... which is d:\inetpub\wwwroot\wwwroot.  Not sure why you'd need that from inside the code, though.  Generally if you're going to write files somewhere, you'd want it outside of webpath to help prevent deep links and ensure that user is authorized to download the file.  I use "~/foldername/filename" for src values. (images, js, css...) which in my case from the server's perspective is d:\inetpub\wwwroot\wwwroot\foldername\filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am aware that I can inject IWebHostEnvironment or that I can cache the value on the startup of the application. My question is strictly about accessing it without these methods.

No, you cannot. There's no static built in here with access to this information. You can create your own though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the right approach, it is used for the time being in a POC to apply XSLT transforms in an MVC app

```
WebApplicationBuilder webbuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
RootPath = webbuilder.Environment.WebRootPath;
```

Sorry, this might lead to some unforseen consequences which I am investigating atm in my own app
According to MS the WebApplication.CreateBuilder will create a secondary new IISNativeApplication instance being added to the DI container as singleton which will force IIS to shutdown
Ref: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/asp-net-core-503-server-has-been-shutdown/ba-p/3830338
Everything is fine as long you are in debug mode running your app on Kestrel

**Confirmed!**
Code removed and replaced with a fixed path as POC / quick test
No more IIS instant deaths (Server Shutdown)

Comment: I just used it in a class method where I have to read a json file and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this y doing the following

In your Shared project or common project which is reference by the Web project add the below interface

```
public interface IApplicationContext
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; }
}
```

Then, in the web project add below code

```
public sealed class ApplicationContext : IApplicationContext
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ApplicationContext(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string BaseUrl
    {
        get
        {

            var baseUrl = _webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? AppConstants.BaseUrl.FELocalHostBaseUrl :
                                                           _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.BaseUrl();

            return baseUrl!;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in you need to configure the dependency injection in your Startup.cs or any where that you configure DI as below

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IApplicationContext, ApplicationContext>();
```

Then you can inject the `IApplicationContext` in any service class constructor and access the `baseUrl` like below

```
public sealed class SecurityService
{
    private readonly IApplicationContext _applicationContext;

    public SecurityService(IApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public async Task<ResponseResult> SendResetPasswordEmail(ForgotPasswordModel forgotPasswordModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var baseUrl = _applicationContext.BaseUrl;

        return new ResponseResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though this is detailed, it does not answer the question. It was specifically asked to not use dependency injection or a cached value: `My question is strictly about accessing it without these methods`. Please read before answering.